# Selenium Rasberry pi repeating python code

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cron

I have wrote some code on python which runs perfectly in terminal.

However when I try to set it up to repeat via crontab the python code doesnt seem to run.

I have setup the code within crontab as listed below

```
* * * * * python3 ~/Desktop/sc.py > ~/Desktop/cronlog.txt 2>&1
```

This it the output from the cronlog

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/sc.py", line 9, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 50, in __init__
    keep_alive,
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 64, in __init__
    options=options,
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 205, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 289, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 344, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium-browser is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
#0 0x000000a4a618 <unknown>
#1 0x0000007b09f4 <unknown>
#2 0x0000007d2814 <unknown>
#3 0x0000007cec04 <unknown>
#4 0x00000080528c <unknown>
#5 0x0000007ffa14 <unknown>
#6 0x0000007d8478 <unknown>
#7 0x0000007d93a4 <unknown>
#8 0x000000a77944 <unknown>
#9 0x000000a8990c <unknown>
#10 0x000000a89550 <unknown>
#11 0x000000a8ad40 <unknown>
#12 0x000000a78944 <unknown>
#13 0x000000a8afec <unknown>
#14 0x000000a6f3ac <unknown>
#15 0x000000aa26e8 <unknown>
#16 0x000000aa2858 <unknown>
#17 0x000000abcf4c <unknown>
#18 0x0000f7a6e494 start_thread
#19 0x000000000000 <unknown>
```

I have output the log but I do not under my error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WebDriverException: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist while trying to initiate Chrome Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642308/webdriverexception-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesnt-exist-while-t)